# How to use type-parameterized components with scalajs-react

Tags: scala, scala.js, scalajs-react

I am using scalajs 0.6.15 with scalajs-react 0.11.3 and reactjs 15.4.2.

Consider a component `SomeComp` where the type of a value of the `Props` needs to be parameterized.

Since the type needs to be known when using the component builder I wrap the component inside a class.

```
class SomeComp[T]() {
  case class Props(t: T, onChange: T => Callback)

  val component = ReactComponentB[Props]("SomeComp")...

  def apply(t: T, onChange:T => Callback) = component(Props(t, onChange))
}
```

this works. the problem is, that the component gets remounted with every rerender of the parent, unless the user of `SomeComp` creates first an instance of `SomeComp` and uses this instance in the parent's `render` method.

my hack solution to avoid this is:

```
object SomeComp {
  val genericComp = SomeComp[Any]()

  def apply[T](t: T, onChange: T => Callback) = genericComp(
    t = t, 
    onChange = (a: Any) => onChange(a.asInstanceOf[T])
  )
}
```

is there a better, less boilercode, less awful way? any suggestions?

---

**Update**
After @Golly's (thx for your elaborate answer!) suggestions I find the second solution most elegant and want to post it here for completeness:

```
object SomeComp {
  trait Props{
    type T
    val t: T
    val onChange: T => Callback
  }

  // use Props#T if you need to reference T
  val component = ReactComponentB[Props]("SomeComp")...

  def apply[_T](_t: _T, _onChange: _T => Callback) = {
    val props = new Props {
      type T = _T
      val t = _t
      val onChange = _onChange
    }
    component(props)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a few attempts over the years at polymorphic components and have given up on perfection. If we accept minor imperfections then there are adequate, even nice solutions:

1a) Class around builder. Exactly what you had in your first example *except* one important difference: only create one class per type. Creating a new class for the same type results in an un-mount/re-mount as you saw (because React thinks the components are different), where as if you do something like this:

```
final class SomeComp[A] private[SomeComp] () {
  val component = ReactComponentB[Props]("SomeComp")...
}
object SomeComp {
  val Int = new SomeComp[Int]
  val String = new SomeComp[String]
}
```

If you don't know the types upfront, that's fine too, just create the class for your type once and put it in the companion object of the *callee*. It's a small imperfection that you need to create a singleton per type but *everything* else remains simple.

1b) Similar to above except using a function instead of a class. Create once per-type (per-callee optionally) and reuse.

2) I wouldn't recommend this but you could use existential types instead of universal, specifically make the type parameter a type member.

```
class Props {
  type T
  val value: T
  val onChange: T => Callback
}
```

Now the component is monomorphic but you'll need some boilerplate to create and use the Props class nicely.

Btw, if you're creating a (T x T → Callback) yourself, there's a built-in one that you can use instead: https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/master/doc/EXTRA.md#statesnapshot (doc is for 1.0.0-RC1+, used to be two classes: {Reusable,Exeternal}Var in pre-1.0 days)